# Change text color with jscolor

Tags: javascript, jscolor

I use http://jscolor.com/ for color manipulations and I need to be able to change text color in this button `<a href="#" id="button_cont" >Call to action</a>`. So far I only found this piece of code close to my situation but it's not working for me either.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

     function update(jscolor) {
    $('#button_cont').css("color", "#" + jscolor);}

    </script>


    <input type="text" class="jscolor" onchange="update(this.jscolor);" /> 

<a href="#" id="button_cont" >Call to action</a>
```

Comment: First, did you even include the jscolor.js script in your page ?

Comment: Of course, I can now change bg in this button but I need else the font color to change

Comment: Have you included jQuery library ? What does the console say ? any error ?

Comment: I just tried and its all working.

Comment: What is not working? Is the blue turning red? Are you getting errors in the console?

Comment: Only input changes colors but not the text of the button

Comment: You did not include jQuery, it wont ever work. Please include jQuery or use vanilla Js.

Comment: I have this in the head section: <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

Comment: It was color: #ffffff!important; in my css, I removed the !important and now the answer below works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `onchange` callback to update your button text color.

```html
<body>
  <input type="text" class="jscolor" onchange="update(this.jscolor);" />
  <a href="#" id="button_cont">Call to action</a>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function update(jscolor) {
      $("#button_cont").css("color", "#" + jscolor);
      // document.getElementById('button_cont').style.color = '#' + jscolor;
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

Remember to include your script import

```html
<script src="jscolor.js"></script>
```

and jQuery of course

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: At the begining it didn't work but do you know what it was? It was color: #ffffff!important; I removed !important and now it works! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can call `.style.color` to the element and use whatever color you need to change the  button to. I have always called `.style` whenever I want to change a CSS attribute. Call

```
document.getElementById("button_cont").style.color("red");
```

if you want to change the color of an element to red, for example.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice it was an element.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to do it, would you please update your answer with the code?